# How to connect SAP ERP 6.0 to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, sap-erp

I have the requirement where I need to extract the data from SAP ERP 6.0 system to Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express Edition.

How to Extract data from SAP to SQL? what possible connectors are available and what Prerequisites are required regarding Windows Operating System, SQL server version etc?

Comment: Legal issues aside (and SAP sees these as significant) I presume you have a very limited technology toolset?
The operating system is irrelevant as is the SQL server version. 

How are you intending to get at the data? The underlying database (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, DB2 maybe even HANA) or via RFC / Web Service?